What is the return value of an AFTER FOR EACH ROW trigger function?
Is it necessary to return NEW or is NULL sufficient? Has it any meaning to return anything in an AFTER trigger?

I'm no expert on Postgres triggers (in fact I found them somewhat counter-intuitive) but to my limited knowledge RETURN is only relevant for BEFORE triggers. For AFTER triggers the result is ignored: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

@Lennart-SlavaUkraini Thanks! I found it. I was searching on the create trigger page, which was the wrong place.
